# HTML Image Insertion Django

Tags: python, html, django, image, http

I'm working to build a django web application. I'm using adobe brackets for the html and I'm trying to use an image from my folders on the website. The image appears during the brackets simulation, but not during django runserver.

here is my folder directory:

```
mysite-
    Images-
        livestream-
            helloworld.jpg
    templates-
        livestream-
            helloWorld.html
```

This is a very simplified version of the site, but you get the idea.

My html code asks for the image:

```
<img src="../../Images/livestream/helloworld.jpg" alt="helloWorld" width="590" height="269">
```

when I run the django server it returns:

`[18/Jul/2013 09:11:40] "GET /livestream/Images/livestream/helloworld.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2605`

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set your `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in your settings, as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#referring-to-static-files-in-templates) to point to your `Images` folder and then just type in

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}livestream/helloworld.jpg" alt="helloWorld" width="590" height="269">
```

This is the standard approach to manage static files, and will turn out useful in the future as well

Comment: Thanks, you opened my eyes to a part of django that I didn't know existed. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with how your [`staticfiles` app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) related settings are set up for your project.

You should also use the [`static` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) in order to fetch your static media.

For example, *assuming* that your structure under the location of *any* filepath within the [`STATICFILES_DIRS` tuple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATICFILES_DIRS) is the following:

```
{{STATICFILES_ROOT_DIR}}/Images/livestream/helloworld.jpg
```

you can fetch the static file using:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% static "Images/livestream/helloworld.jpg" as myimg %}
<img src="{{ myimg }}" alt="helloworld" />
```